# Como saber se foreach está percorrendo último item da lista

Tags: c#

Criei uma aplicação em **console** e um **foreach** para percorrer minha lista de inteiros:

```
var lista = new List<int>() { 2, 6, 1, 4, 20, 21};

int count = 0;
foreach (var item in lista)
{
   count++;

   //if(???)
       //count = 0;

   //....
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Como saber se meu **foreach** está no último item da minha lista?

Pois se ele estiver percorrendo o último elemento, dentro do if irei zerar minha variável count.

Comment: A minha pergunta é: Por quê????
Se você quer o count não precisa de nenhum foreach, apenas pegue o `Count` da sua lista..

Comment: @LeandroAngelo É que esse count quando é o ultimo elemento da minha lista ele tem que ser zerado, por isso coloquei //... pois tem mais implementação que não achei necessário colocar.

Comment: se seu count (chame de i, j, x, "seila o que", pra não confundir) for igual ao `Count` da sua list vc estará no final.

Comment: Se você estiver em um ambiente em que a lista não é alterada durante a iteração, então o `foreach` das coleções da biblioteca padrão vai percorrer todos os elementos sim (esse é o seu caso). **TALVEZ** falhe no caso de algum `foreach` feito manualmente para uma coleção sua

Comment: @samuelrvg poderia colocar o que deseja fazer dentro do laço e do `if`? Provavelmente tem como fazer esse código de forma muito melhor.

Comment: @Maniero Poderia até colocar, mas nesse caso ficaria mais complexo de explicar como está funcionando, pois estou usando um vetor dentro desse loop para enviar comandos para um módulo de balança, estou trabalhando com protocolo modbus e a biblioteca que uso para enviar esses comandos aceita um vetor para enviar, o loop é justamente para criar vários comandos e enviar esses comandos conforme uma tabela especifica que tenho... mas de qualquer forma, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @samuelrvg Tudo bem então, mas acho que poderia fazer de forma melhor que isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente você precisa de algo melhor, mas não tem como saber sem maiores detalhes na pergunta.

O que você pede é isto

```
void Main()
{
    var lista = new List<int>() { 2, 6, 1, 4, 20, 21};

    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in lista)
    {
        count++;        
        Console.WriteLine(count);

        if(count == lista.Count) {
           count = 0;   
           Console.WriteLine("último");
        }          
    }
}
```